# How could I concatenate np.ndarray in loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have some ndarray that values is constructed in loop. I want to concatenate these ndarray to a single array with axis 0. How could I do it in python? This is my example

```
input: 1x2x32x32x64,1x2x32x32x64,1x2x32x32x64,1x2x32x32x64
output 4x2x32x32x64
```

What I have done:

```
import numpy as np
A_concate=np.array([])
for i in range (4):
    a_i = np.random.rand(1,2,32,32,64)
    print (a_i.shape)
    A_concate= np.concatenate(A_concate,a_i, axis=0)
print (A_concate.shape)
```

The error

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "python", line 6, in <module>
> TypeError: Argument given by name ('axis') and position (2)
> ```

Online code: https://repl.it/repls/HugeKnownSolidstatedrive

First solution using vstack

```
import numpy as np
A_concate=[]
for i in range (4):
    a_i = np.random.rand(1,2,32,32,64)
    print (a_i.shape)
    A_concate.append(a_i)
A_concate=np.vstack((A_concate))
print (A_concate.shape)
```

Comment: Don't you just want `hstack` or `vstack` here?

Comment: Can you not build a list and concatenate a list of arrays at the end?

Comment: Any method are welcome. I just care about the output `A_concate` must be np.ndarray

Comment: `np.vstack((a,b,c,d))`

Comment: @user3483203: It is in lopp, so we do not know where is a,b,c,d. We only have `a_i`

Comment: @jpp: it make take more time when we concatenate the array directly

Comment: `numpy.concatenate((a1, a2, ...), axis=0, out=None)` is the template. A_concate and a_i must follow this instance.

Comment: The first argument of `concatenate` is supposed to be a list of the arrays you want to join.  The error is because you didn't pay close enough attention to the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution with [`numpy.vstack`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html)

```
import numpy as np
A_stack = np.random.rand(1,2,32,32,64)
for i in range (3):
    a_i = np.random.rand(1,2,32,32,64)
    A_stack= np.vstack([A_stack,a_i])
print (A_stack.shape) # Outputs (4, 2, 32, 32, 64)
```